# How do I return a true or false on onclick event

Tags: javascript, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I have an anchor tag that contains a document, it will either download or if it is a PDF it will display the document. This works great, but not I have placed on some of the document objects in my model a password protection feature, to prevent only authorized users the ability to view. 
so I have a click event that will display a modal and have the user enter a password, then I am calling an .ajax command to return either a true or false. but what I don't is how to return the true or false.

Here is the markup:

```
<a href="@link.DocumentPath" onclick="checkAuth(@link.Id); ">@link.Title</a>
```

Here is the javascript:

```
var checkAuth = function(id) {

    var hostname = location.hostname;
    var host = '@System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["hostroot"]';
    if (hostname == "localhost")
        host = "";


    $(".modal-dialog").css({
        "left": 0,
        "top": 200,

    });

    $(".modal-body").css({
        "background-color": "darkgreen"
    })


    $(".modal-title").text("This Document is Password Protected");

    var url = host + "/Communities/CheckAuth/" + id;

    $("#inviteDialog").load(url, function () {
        $("#inviteModal").modal("show");
    })

};
```

then here is the View

```
public ActionResult CheckAuth(int? id)
{
    var encrypted = db.CommunityDocs.Where(x=>x.Id == id).Select(x=>x.Password).SingleOrDefault();

    ViewBag.encryptedPwd = encrypted;
    return PartialView();
}
```

Lastly, here is the Get

```
<form id="checkAuth">
    <label class="sr-only" for="teamEmailAddress">Enter Password</label>
    <input class="form-control" type="text" name="password" id="password" placeholder="Enter Password to view">
    <input class="form-control" type="hidden" name="encrypted" id="encrypted" value="@ViewBag.encryptedPwd" /><br />
    <a href="#" id="btnSubmit" class="btn btn-default">Enter</a>
</form>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {

        $("#btnSubmit").click(function () {
            // Host
            var hostname = location.hostname;
            var host = '@System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["hostroot"]';
            if (hostname == "localhost")
                host = "";

            var formdata = $("#checkAuth").serialize();
            var encryptedPwd = $("encryptedPwd").val();
            var password = $("password").val();

            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: host + "/Communities/DeCryptPwd/",

                data: formdata,
                success: function (data) {
                    $("#inviteModal").modal("hide");
                    // window.location.href = host + "/Communities/EditCommunity/" + communityId;
                    alert(data);
                },
                error: function (errorData) { alert(errorData); }
            })
        });
    });
</script>
```

It will return True or False, but I just don't know how to process to return the True or False.

the DeCryptPwd method:

```
 public bool DeCryptPwd(string encrypted, string password)
        {
            /* Extract the bytes */
            byte[] hashBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(encrypted);
            /* Get the salt */
            byte[] salt = new byte[16];
            Array.Copy(hashBytes, 0, salt, 0, 16);
            /* Compute the hash on the password the user entered */
            var pbkdf2 = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes(password, salt, 10000);
            byte[] hash = pbkdf2.GetBytes(20);
            /* Compare the results */
            for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
                if (hashBytes[i + 16] != hash[i])
                    return false;


            return true;
        }
```

Comment: You need to return a JsonResult on your DeCryptPwd action method by using Json(true) or Json(false). That would return a json object with the value true or false. You need to change your ajax call changing dataType to json

Comment: thank you for your response, but it does return true or false, I just need to know how to pass that back so that the pdf or whatever href in the anchor tag does not display or download

Comment: Can you show your code in your DeCryptPwd method?

Comment: I added it, basically I need to pass the bool returned from this method to prevent the download or display of the document in the Anchor tag, but I am confused as to how to do this

Comment: @PaulT.Rykiel can you please put the code for the action method "Communities/DeCryptPwd" as well. With that I think I can help